# Does Exchange ActiveSync save mails in phone?

Tags: exchange, activesync, smartphone

We have a lot of smartphones using **Exchange ActiveSync** to receive mails. Does the phone save these mails in its internal memory? For example: to work with them when we are off-line. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the items that the clients have already been downloaded from the server they are stored offline on the client, except there are e.g. some attachments that are not automatically downloaded to the client during the reception.

On my Android phone I can also access the items that were already received without a connection to the server.